# Find a vector's component given that the vector is perpendicular to another vector

Tags: vectors

What value of $a$ makes vector ${\bf u} = (a,1)$ perpendicular to ${\bf v} = (3,2)$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Set the dot product $\vec u \cdot \vec v$ to be $0$

Comment: Thank you. Alright I got it .

Answer (score 2):

If $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are perpendicular, then $\vec u\cdot\vec v=0$.

Thus $(a,1)\cdot(3,2)=3a+2=0$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I can now thanks to you. @J. W. Tanner.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you visualize the problem:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @David G. Stork.  It helps a lot