# Find the angle between the vectors

Tags: vectors

Hello I am not sure of the answers I gave. Can I have your opinion on them, please?

Q1: Three vectors $\vec u$,  $\vec v$ and  $\vec w$ of length 5, 12 and 15. If their sum gives $\vec 0$ what's the angle between the  vectors   $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ ?

Answer 1: 90 degrees

Q2: Two vectors $\vec u$,  $\vec v$ of length 3 and 5, respectively, are added, and the result vector is perpendicular to  $\vec u$. Give the angle that separates $\vec u$ and  $\vec v$.

Answer 2 : 90 degrees

Thanks  in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you mean $5, 12, $ and $13$?  That would be $90^\circ$ (cf. Pythagorean Theorem)

Comment: No, it's actually written 5, 12, 15

Comment: Then it's not $90^\circ$

Comment: and for Q2, the angle that separates $\vec u$ and $\vec u + \vec v$ is $90^\circ$

Comment: Try $\vec u \cdot \vec v=|u| |v| \cos\theta$

Comment: But I don't know the components of each vector.

Comment: in Q2, you [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448456/find-a-vectors-component-given-that-the-vector-is-perpendicular-to-another-vect) $\vec u\cdot (\vec u + \vec v)=0$

Comment: I got it now it's 180 degree. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)
That $\mathbb u + \mathbb v + \mathbb w = 0$ means that if we place the vectors head to tail to head to tail, they form a triangle.

By the law of cosines

$15^2 = 5^2 + 12^2 - 2(5)(12)\cos \theta\\
\frac {225 - 144 - 25}{120} = -\cos\theta\\
\frac {56}{120} = \cos\theta\\
\theta = \arccos -\frac {7}{15}$

But that is the angle between $u,v$ when they are head to tail.  When they are tail to tail you will get the supplement of that angle.

$\arccos \frac 7{15}$

You could also do this with $\|\mathbb u + \mathbb v\| = \|\mathbb w\|$

b)
$(\mathbb u+\mathbb v)\cdot \mathbb u = 0\\
\mathbb u\cdot \mathbb u + \mathbb u\cdot \mathbb v = 0\\
\|\mathbb u\|^2 + \|\mathbb u\|\|\mathbb v\|\cos\theta = 0\\
9 + 15\cos\theta = 0\\
\theta = \arccos-\frac 35$

Answer (score 1):

1) Start with $v+u+w=0$ and square,

$$v^2+u^2+w^2 +2(u\cdot v-w^2)=0$$

Thus, the angle is

$$\cos\theta = \frac{u\cdot v }{|u||v|}
= -\frac{ v^2+u^2-w^2 }{2|u||v|}=\frac7{15}$$

2) $(u+v)\cdot u= 0$ leads to

$$\cos\theta =  \frac{u\cdot v }{|u||v|}= -\frac{u^2}{|u||v|}=
-\frac{|u|}{|v|}=-\frac35 $$

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are wrong.

For question $1$, answer would be $90^\circ$, if the question were $5, 12, $ and $1\color{red}3$.

For question $2$, the answer is not $90^\circ$ nor $180^\circ.$

If $\vec u\cdot (\vec u+\vec v)=0,$ then $\vec u\cdot \vec u=-\vec u\cdot \vec v $,

so $|\vec u|^2=-|\vec u||\vec v|\cos\theta,$ and you are given $|\vec u|$ and $|\vec v|$;

you should be able to find $\theta$ from here.

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be as follows (I'm assuming you are working with real spaces). You know that:
$$u\cdot v = ||u||||v||\cos\theta$$
and you want to find out the value of $\theta$. For this, you need to calculate $u\cdot v$. But note that, because $u+v+w = 0$, we have:
$$ 0 = (u+v-w)\cdot (u+v+w) = u\cdot u + u\cdot v + u\cdot w + v\cdot u + v\cdot v +v\cdot w -w\cdot u -w\cdot v -w\cdot w = ||u||^{2}+||v||^{2}-||w||^{2}+2 u\cdot v$$ 
So, you know that $2 u\cdot v = ||w||^{2}-||u||^{2}-||v||^{2}$.